# virt-manager VM cannot access outside network when VPN is enabled

Tags: ubuntu, virtual-machine, vpn, virt-manager

I am running *CentOS7* as a VM on *Virtual Machine Manager* (`virt-manager 2.2.1`) on `Ubuntu 20.04.1`. On the same Ubuntu machine I am running *AnyConnect 4.9.03047* to connect via VPN.

When the VPN is not connected the VM has access to the local network and the internet. But as soon as I connect AnyConnect to the VPN the VM loses connection.

The Virtual Network Interface is configured with the default configuration:
Network source: NAT
Device model: virtio

Is there anything I am missing that would allow network access while VPN is connected?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default, the VM on *Virtual Machine Manager* uses a NAT Virtual Network Interface. I had to switch to a bridged connection in order to gain network access.

Steps to create a bridge connection:

1. *Add Hardware*

   - Opens *Add New Virtual Hardware*
2. Choose *Network*
3. From *Network source:* choose *Host device `xyz: macvtap`*

   - `xyz` is the device name
4. The *Source mode:* will switch to *Bridge* with a warning message.
5. *Device model: virtio*
6. Deactivate the original default NAT interface.
7. Start the VM.